# How to caculate one row base on another row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

[data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Hzh.png)

Sorry for inconvenience of picture of the data !

I get this data, I try to calculate EMA_20 a row base on EMA_20 row before

Example: calculate EMA_20 at index 1003 base on EMA_20 at index 1004, I try using vectorization for speed up but don't know how to specify the index at row

```
def vec_EMA(data ,indicator = 20):
    K = 2/(indicator + 1)
    if (data['index'].values[0] == len(data) - 1):
        return data["close"] * K + data["SMA_" + str(indicator)] * (1- K)
    return data["close"] * K + data["EMA_20"][data.index + 1] * (1- K)

new_data['EMA_20'] = vec_EMA(new_data)
```

The result just like on picture but it not exactly what I try to do

Expected out put is:

EMA_20 at index 1003 = data['close'] at index 1003 * K + EMA_20 at index 1004 * (1 - K) where K = 2/(20+1)

result is 47.13531746031746 not 39.158333

Comment: you need to provide the data as text (use a smaller abstract example id needed), ans please provide the expected output

Comment: You should use .shift method. will seal the deal for you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead trying to update the dataframe directly taking a list and finally returning the list from the function would be an easier approach

```
def vec_EMA(df,indicator=20):
  EMA_20_list=[]
  K = 2/(indicator + 1)
  for index in df.index :
    if index==len(df)-1: #indexing is done in reverse order starting from 0
      value=df.loc[index,'close']*K + (1-K)*df.loc[index,"SMA_" +str(indicator)]
      EMA_20_list.append(value)
    else:
      value=df.loc[index,'close']*K+ (1-K)* EMA_20_list[-1] 
      #EMA_20_list[-1] return above rows value
      EMA_20_list.append(value)
  return EMA_20_list

  df['EMA_20']=vec_EMA(df)
```